# When exactly is an operator between normed spaces well defined? A particular case.

Tags: functional-analysis, definite-integrals, solution-verification, normed-spaces, operator-theory

### Generic question

Let's say we have two normed spaces $X = (X,\|\cdot\|_X)$ and $Y = (Y, \|\cdot\|_Y)$ and an operator $T\colon X \to Y$. My generic question is pretty simple: are there "universal" conditions that allow one to conclude that $T$ is well defined? By "universal" I mean if I could explain the well definedness to someone who learnt math in the other side of the world.

In literacture, I have seen authors prove different things to show well definedness. Some show that, in fact, $Tx$ exists for every $x \in X$, others show that $Tx \in Y,$ for every $x \in X$ and some even show that $x = x' \Rightarrow Tx = Tx'$, for every pair of elements $x,x' \in X.$ Even at my lectures, my lecturer proves well definedness with diferent condition (not equivalent ones) at different times (maybe because the other conditions are trivial $(?)$ ).

So, my intuition tells me that, in a general way, to prove that $T$ is well defined, one should (always) show the following points:

- For every $x \in X, Tx$ must exist.
- For every $x \in X, Tx$ must belong to $Y$.
- Given two vectors $x,x' \in X,$ if $x = x'$ then $Tx = Tx'.$

With this in mind, follows my particular example.

### Particular Example

Consider the normed space $\mathcal C[0,1]$ equipped with the usual infinity norm and consider the operator $T\colon \mathcal C[0,1] \to \mathcal C[0,1]$ such that $Tf(x) = \int_0^x f(t) \, dt.$
In an attempt to show that $T$ is well defined, I was able to prove that $Tf$ must exist for every function $f \in \mathcal C[0,1]$ and also that $Tf \in \mathcal C[0,1],$ for every function $f \in \mathcal C[0,1].$ There is one thing (according to my assumption in the generic question) left to prove:

$$\forall f,g \in \mathcal C[0,1], \, f = g \Rightarrow Tf = Tg. $$

To do so, consider two arbitrary functions $f,g \in \mathcal C[0,1]$ such that $f=g.$ Then,
$$ Tf - Tg = \int_0^x f(t) \, dt - \int_0^x g(t) \, dt = \int_0^x f(t) - g(t) \, dt = \int_0^x [f(t)-g(t)] \, dt = 0.$$
Is this formal enough?

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: There is nothing special about normed spaces. To show that a candidate for a function is well defined, you just have to show that the candidate satisfies the definition of a function. That is, for every $x$ in the domain of the function, there is a unique value $y$ in the co-domain of the function.

Comment: Well-defined-ness is a property of functions in general, and operators are just a special case of that. The main thing to worry about is if the domain is defined as a quotient $X_0/\sim$ for some bigger set $X_0$ with an equivalence relation $\sim.$ Then if you define a function in terms of $x_0\in X_0,$ you need to show that the definition gives the same result for any $x_1\in X_0$ with $x_0\sim x_1.$

Comment: But what you need to show depends on that equivalence relation, and how you defined the would-be function.

Comment: @Seeker That's exactly what my last bullet stands for (I believe)... But besides this, I still feel like the other two bullets are relevant for well-defined-ness.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews None of that applies in my particular example, I believe - my main question was about the three bullets I've shown in the heading **generic question**.

Comment: @Aqualight Your bullet points are just breaking up the definition of a function into three separate parts.

Comment: @Aqualight The third bullet is the one that comes up most often with equivalence relations. It certainly isn't any work here for this particular example.

Comment: @Seeker So, to prove well-defined-ness, proving the three bullets I stated is enough?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I agree with you, but what I did in the particular example looks ok?

Comment: @Aqualight Yes.

Comment: Those three bullets are enough to prove it is a function $X\to Y,$ but well-definedness is really just the third bullet.